# Scrapy Splash screenshot webpage from png to webp without saving the rendered image

Tags: python, scrapy-splash

Scrapy splash screenshot webpages and converting image.png to image.webp on the fly. Images takes a lot of memory and scrapy splash returns .png file. I crawl a lot of webpages so I need to convert it to image.webp to lessen the disk consumption.

Answer (score 0):

Use BytesIO() in converting png image to webp

```
import scrapy
import json
import base64
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

class WebScreenshots(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'screenshot'

    def start_requests(self):
        links = ["your", "review", "links"]
        for url in links:
            yield SplashRequest(
                                    url=url,
                                    callback=self.parse,
                                    dont_filter=True,
                                    args={
                                            'html': 1,
                                            'png': 1,
                                            'wait': 20,
                                            'url':url,
                                            'render_all': 1
                                        },
                                    endpoint='render.json'
                                )


    def parse(self, response):
        """
           file_name = I just use the link as a file name, you can specify own file name.
           directory = the path where you will saved the converted image 
        """
        url = response.url
        file_name = "{}.webp".format(url)
        imgdata = base64.b64decode(response.data['png'])
        image = Image.open(BytesIO(imgdata))
        image.save(directory + file_name)

        print (file_name)
        print ('screenshot done...')
```